# Disallow saving an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to disallow saving an Excel (.xls) file?
(Should also work in Numbers on OSX)

Comment: It would help is you further explain the situation.  Do yo mean protecting an existing spreadsheet from change?

Comment: What's the purpose of not allowing a save?  Using a password can help, but can be cracked.  Do you want the users to manipulate cells, enter formulas, etc. just not save? Or is it just for them to look at, and you don't want anyone saving accidentally after editing?  If the latter, maybe just print to PDF/some other non-editable format?  Make sure this question isn't "creating" an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

As in change it so it is read only, you mean? You can do that with a password if I'm not mistaken.

But disallow saving - I don't see the point - someone could always copy the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a macro on the Before_Save event, but circumventing it only means disabling macros.

```
       ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

If you forced macros to be enabled to even view the content that might help, but won't ensure not saving.
[Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Registry.htm) has some interesting TimeBombRegistry code you might adapt